# NSMutableArray crashes when adding after proper initialization

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsarray, type-conversion

I have an NSMutableArray defined as a property, synthesized and I have assigned a newly created instance of an NSMutableArray. But after this my application always crashes whenever I try adding an object to the NSMutableArray.

**Page.h**

```
@interface Page : NSObject  
{  
    NSString *name;  
    UIImage *image;  
    NSMutableArray *questions;  
}
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *name;  
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIImage *image;  
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSMutableArray *questions;  
@end
```

**Page.m**

```
@implementation Page  
@synthesize name, image, questions;  
@end
```

**Relevant code**

```
Page *testPage = [[Page alloc] init];  
testPage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Cooperatief  leren Veenman-11.jpg"];  
testPage.name = [NSString stringWithString:@"Cooperatief  leren Veenman-11.jpg"];  
testPage.questions = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];  
[testPage.questions addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:arc4random()]];
```

The debugger reveals that the moment I use `testPage.questions = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];` the type of testPage.questions changes from NSMutableArray* to __NSArrayL* (or __NSArrayI*, not sure). I suspect this to be the problem, but I find it extremely odd. Anyone know what's happening here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you've declared the property as `copy`.  This means your setter is going to be implemented something like this:

```
- (void) setQuestions:(NSMutableArray *)array {
  if (array != questions) {
    [questions release];
    questions = [array copy];
  }
}
```

The kicker here is that if you `-copy` an array (whether immutable or mutable), you will *always* get an immutable `NSArray`.

So to fix this, change the property to be `retain` instead of `copy`, and also fix this memory leak:

```
testPage.questions = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

It should be:

```
testPage.questions = [NSMutableArray array];
```

Comment: Hmm, didn't think that would be it, but it works! I used `copy` since a lot of questions on here suggest using copy whenever something is Mutable. Thanks :D

Comment: @SpacyRicochet: You use `copy` when you want to ensure that the resulting property value is *immutable*.  You see this most often with `NSString` properties: you `copy` them so that the string itself can't change out from underneath you.  Since your property is *supposed* to be mutable, you can't use `copy`. :)

Comment: Thank you!  This would have taken me much longer to figure out.  :)

Answer (score 2):

@property (nonatomic, copy) This setter declaration "copy" probably cast to NSArray why not retain or assign? I would retain anyway

Comment: +1, though the new value is not cast to an `NSArray`.  The method is actually making an immutable copy.

Comment: Thanks, BTW Is any way to see what code is generated from those directive like @property ?

Comment: Other than looking at the raw assembly, there is not.

Answer (score 1):

You can also create a mutable copy method like so:

```
- (void)setQuestions:(NSMutableArray *)newArray
{
    if (questions != newArray) 
    {
        [questions release];
        questions = [newArray mutableCopy];
    }
}
```

Comment: Found out about this afterwards as well. Good method, though I use it for methods that return normal arrays I want to alter.